# Open facebook Messenger Android error: Some dialogs are only supported starting API 14

Tags: react-native

I'm opening a Facebook Messenger dialog with the following code:

```
 MessageDialog.canShow(this.state.messageContent).then(

    function(canShow) {

       return MessageDialog.show(tmp.state.messageContent);

    }

  ).then(function(result) {

      if (typeof result == "undefined")
        return;

      if (result.isCancelled) {
        alert('Share operation was cancelled');
      } else {
        alert('Share was successful with postId: ' + result.postId);
      }
    },
    function(error) {
      alert('Share failed with error: ' + error);
    }
  );
```

This works fine on Android 4, but not on Android 6. I get the following error message:
"Share failed with error. Error: Unable to show the provided content via the web or the installed version of the Facebook app. Some dialogs are only supported starting API 14."

The latest version of the Facebook app is installed on the device and I'm using the latest facebook SDK (4.17).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: I have no clue why the messages is referring to API before API 14 since I'm compiling with API 23.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why:

Seems like it was because Facebook Messenger wasn't installed on the device. Calling the web function does not seem to work from Android 6.0.